# excel vba sort by color and then values

Tags: vba, excel

I've been trying to adapt another answer to my situation and I can't get it to work. I'm trying to sort by the color of one cell (they are either no color or one specific color), and then by the value in a second cells. Here's my code:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
xL.Sheets(sheet).Sort.SortFields.Clear
xL.Sheets(sheet).Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("B1:B" + CStr(rowCount)), _
        xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(216, 228, 188)
xL.Sheets(sheet).Sort.SortFields.Add Range("H1:H" + CStr(rowCount)), _
        xlSortOnValues, xlDescending, , xlSortNormal
With xL.Sheets(sheet).Sort
    .SetRange ("A1:M" + Trim(Str(rowCount)))
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .Apply
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

When I run, I get the following error: Run-time error '-2147417851 (80010105)': Method 'Add' of object 'SortFields' failed. It is happening on the first ".SortFields.Add". Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Before `Range()`, add the sheet you expect it to be on, i.e. `xL.Sheets(sheet).Range("B1:B" + CStr(rowCount)`

Comment: Thanks Bruce! Sometimes all you need is a second set of eyes.

Comment: Did that solve your issue??  I've become such a stickler for the "anchoring" after spending many hours myself not seeing that I forgot to do it.  Always always always make sure your ranges are qualified :D

Comment: Yep that solved it! I knew it was something simple, just couldn't see what it was.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the basic script for sorting:

For Office 2013:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet).Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet).Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("B2:B" & rowCount), _
    xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(216, 228, 188)
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet).Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:M" & rowCount)
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet).Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet).Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B2:B" & rowCount), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet).Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:M" & rowCount)
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```